# paginación en galeria dinamica ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, imagen

Estoy creando imagenes dinamicamente, trayendo de la base de datos al dirección donde se encuentran.
El problema es son demasiadas imágenes y necesito un paginado pero no se como implementarlo ya que no utilizo table ni algo similar.
Este es el código:

```
    <body class="cuerpo">
<asp:Label ID="Cuenta" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div id="mycontainerclass" style="color: #f6f7f8;">
         <button class="btn bg-light-blue" runat="server" onserverclick="Click_Dia">BY DAY</button>
             <button class="btn bg-light-blue" runat="server" onserverclick="Click_Semana">BY WEEK</button>
     </div>
<div>

 <div class="gallery-photos clearfix">
    <div class="photo-thumbnails" runat="server" id="divGallery">
    </div>
    <div id="big-photo" class="big-photo">
        <div id="mydiv" runat="server"></div>
        <center>
            <p id="ms">Bienvenido a KudoCards</p>
            <p id="contenido"></p>
        </center>

        <img src="image_DashBoard/kudocards2.png"/>
    </div>


</div>
</div>
</form>
```

El code behind es este donde le crean:

```
 StringBuilder objstring = new StringBuilder();
        if (objdt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Cuenta.Text = objdt.Rows.Count.ToString();
            for (int i = 1; i < objdt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string cssClass = i == 0 ? "thumbnail current" : "thumbnail";
                objstring.Append("<div class='" + cssClass + "'>");
                objstring.Append("<div class=\"thumbnail-inner\">");
                asunto = objdt.Rows[i]["asunto"].ToString();
                destinatario= objdt.Rows[i]["IdDestinatario"].ToString();
                mensaje = objdt.Rows[i]["Mensaje"].ToString();
                objstring.Append("<img runat=\"server\" ID='"+i+"' src='" + objdt.Rows[i]["imagePath"].ToString()+"' alt='"+asunto+":"+" " +""+destinatario+"' title='"+mensaje+"'/>");
                objstring.Append(" </div>");
                objstring.Append(" </div>");

            }
            divGallery.InnerHtml = objstring.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('No hay Cartas para Mostrar');</script>");
            this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "NewWindow", "window.open('Galeria.aspx', '_self');", true);
        }
        }
```

Este el Jquery para controlar que al darle click se ponga en grande la imágen:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').click(function () {
    // Setting class "current" to the thumbnail that was clicked.
    jQuery('.photo-thumbnails .thumbnail').removeClass('current');
    jQuery(this).addClass('current');
    // Getting "src" attribute of the image that was clicked.
    var path = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('src');
    var mensaje = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('alt');
    var contend = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('title');
    // Setting "src" attribute of the big image.
    jQuery('#big-photo img').attr('src', path);
    jQuery('#ms').text(mensaje);
    jQuery('#contenido').text(contend);
    console.log(contend);
});
```

});

Comment: Sobre lo que tienes avanzado, son varias cosas que se podrían modificar y se tendría que definir la manera como quieres realizar el paginado, a través de un Postback o por Ajax. Quizás te recomiende usar el control `Repeater`, para evitar generar la cadena HTML y hacer buen uso de tu variable `objdt` (pienso que es del tipo DataTable). Podrías revisar la Demo y ver el código fuente del ejemplo: [Implement Paging in Repeater control in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Implement-Paging-in-Repeater-control-in-ASPNet.aspx).

Comment: El ejemplo considera, desde la cantidad de registros que debe traer desde una base de datos hasta las funcionalidades del paginado.

Comment: me estaba basando en este ejemplo http://www.aspdotnet-pools.com/2016/09/dynamic-image-gallery-using-jquery-in.html?showComment=1516640177655#c3839044082781970705

Comment: Entonces no creo que tengas problemas con el ejemplo que te envié. Como te digo, al `Repeater` le puedes definir el HTML que quieras y pasar los valores para que no estes generando una cadena concatenada. Sobre la funcionalidad de JQuery no habría ningún problema.